# Uncaught reference error (could not read JSON file)

Tags: javascript, html, json

So, I'm starting to learn JSON handling in javascript, I have an JSON file like this one:

```
[{"name":"Krzysztof Kowalski", "title":"Na Zdrowie", "author":"Jan Kochanowski"}]
```

And I'm trying to print it into a website, if I'm not wrong this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
        <script>
            function updateUser() {
                var configs = JSON.parse(data);
                document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = configs[0].name;
                var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="updateUser()">
        <div id='txt'>
            <p>Test text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Should print the `"name"` field from the first object in JSON, although I get an error like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

EDIT: changed

```
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = data[0].name;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = configs[0].name;
```

Comment: When you parse it shouldn't you use configs[0].name? I assume you parsed because data was serialized as string

Comment: @Aalexander Yeah, it should, my bad, but it still does not want to work after changing it

Comment: That’s not how this works. Including `data.json` as a script does not create a variable `data`. Make an AJAX request using the `fetch()` API to load the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to work, your JSON file must rather look like this:

```
data = '[{"name":"Krzysztof Kowalski", "title":"Na Zdrowie", "author":"Jan Kochanowski"}]'
```

If you prefer to go up with a conventional JSON file, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ should help in that more normal approach.

Comment: That’s not JSON anymore, that’s Javascript…